# Are there any Objective-C compilers for Windows?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Simple question really, and I have Googled it...

Are there any Objective-C compilers that run under windows 7, other than running iOS under VirtualBox or VMWare?

**EDIT:** 
Question changed from emulators to compilers

Comment: Sorry, the mention of iOS made it sound like you were specifically interested in that. Still - if you are going to do Mac dev work, you need to get a Mac.

Comment: @Matt:  Yes, it is looking that way.  I was just trying to get ahead of the learning curve before spending the money

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as an Objective-C emulator. Maybe there is an Objective-C compiler.

If you are referring to an iPhone/iPad/iOS emulator, then the answer is: **no**. You need **Mac OS X** to run a proper **iOS** emulator.

Update: now that you change from emulator to compilers, then the answer is **yes**. You can compile **Objective-C** with a Windows machine using **GCC 4.2** (under Cygwin, or using MinGW). But, do keep in mind that that doesn't mean you will have Cocoa or CocoaTouch frameworks available (which you need to do iOS development).

Answer (score 1):

You can run gcc under Cygwin.

[GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/) and [Cocotron](http://cocotron.org/) are complete(-ish) Cocoa(-ish?) environments.

Answer (score 0):

GCC and possibly MingW have support for Objective-C; in the former case, since the early 90s. However, Obj-C is so closely related to the Foundation libraries that it is of little use elsewhere. In Windows, stick to C++ or C# for the most part.

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090428100046AAWQ8pa